# Auto Assign a Taxonomy Based on a ZipCode in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, taxonomy, drupal-taxonomy

I need to automatically assing a taxonomy term to a node based on its zipcode (field). What would be the best solution to accomplish it ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [`hook_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL)`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi) for `$op == 'presave'` in a custom module.

```
YOURMODULE_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  if ($op == 'presave' && $node->field_zipcode);
  {
    $term = zipcode_get_term($node->field_zipcode);
    $node->taxonomy[$term->tid] = $term;
  }
}
```